# Alert( ) jQuery solo una vez al cargar la página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una función con jQuery que se encarga de leer el stock de una BD. Con ello he establecido un alert( ) de manera que si es inferior a 500, se muestre.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

  $(".stock").each(function(){
   var aux = $(this).attr("id");
   var stock=parseInt($(this).text());
   
     if(stock<=500){
     alert("Alerta de stock en : " + aux);
     }
    });
  });
```

Bueno, esto, no me parece mal y funciona. La cuestión es que cuando refresco la página se muestra de nuevo. Me interesa que solo se muestre una vez por sesión. He visto ejemplos para un click, pero no me interesa esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes apoyarte de un booleano.

Declaras una variable booleana en `false`, luego validas en el `if` si la variable es `false`, de la cual sí o sí entrará ahí, después muestras tu `alert`, y por último, cambias el estado el `true` para que en la siguiente vez no entre al `if`, ya que el `if` valida si la variable booleana es `false`.

```
var estado = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".stock").each(function() {
   var aux = $(this).attr("id");
   var stock=parseInt($(this).text());

   if(stock<=500 && !estado) {
     alert("Alerta de stock en : " + aux);
     estado = true;
   }
 });
});
```

O puedes hacerlo con `localstorage`, intentas obtener el item al principio y te da `false` porque no lo encuentra, y así entras al `if`, y dentro del `if` agregas el item al `localstorage`, para que en la siguiente vez que ingresa tu función, obtengas true y no entra al `if` nuevamente, así entras al `alert` solo 1 vez:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".stock").each(function() {
   var aux = $(this).attr("id");
   var stock=parseInt($(this).text());
   var estado = localStorage.getItem(aux);
  
   if(stock<=500 && !estado) {
     alert("Alerta de stock en : " + aux);
     localStorage.setItem(aux, "true");
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: si! localStorage va genial!. Algún dia caere en estas cosas yo solito ... :) Gracias!